# How to slice a numpy array using index arrays with different shapes?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Let's say that we have the following 2d numpy array:

```
arr = np.array([[1,1,0,1,1],
                [0,0,0,1,0],
                [1,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,1,0,0],
                [0,1,0,0,0]])
```

and the following indices for rows and columns:

```
rows = np.array([0,2,4])
cols = np.array([1,2])
```

The objective is to slice `arr` using `rows` and `cols` to take the following *expected result:*

```
arr_sliced = np.array([[1,0],
                       [0,0],
                       [1,0]])
```

Using directly the arrays as indices like `arr[rows, cols]` leads to:

> IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)

---

So what is the straightforward way to achieve this kind of slicing?

### Update: useful information about the solution

So the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75412114/how-to-slice-a-numpy-array-using-index-arrays-with-different-shapes/75412195#75412195) was simple enough and it demands a basic comprehension about numpy's broadcasting. Someone could read these nice but not so representative [examples](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) from numpy. Also, the [general broadcasting rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules) explains why there is no *shape mismatch* in:

```
arr[rows[:, np.newaxis], cols]
# rows[:, np.newaxis].shape == (3,1)
# cols.shape == (2,)
```

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting the resulting array. Column 1 is the _second_ column and column 2 is the _third. Which doesn't correspond to what you're showing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
arr[rows[:,None], cols[None]]
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 0]])
```

Comment: This way agrees with the 2nd example in: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing. But what I don't understand is why there isn't "shape mismatch" since `rows[:, np.newaxis]` has shape `(3,1)` and `cols[np.newaxis]` has shape `(1,2)`. Could you please elaborate on this please?

Comment: @lezaf because of the shape. If you pass vectors, this slices individual elements, not combinations.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is much quicker than indexing for large arrays.

```
arr[np.ix_([0,2,4],[1,2])]

array([[1, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 0]])
```

document: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html

*This function takes N 1-D sequences and returns N outputs with N dimensions each, such that the shape is 1 in all but one dimension and the dimension with the non-unit shape value cycles through all N dimensions.*